# how to use ctrl + 1 to switch to previous tab in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-quantum

I'm using firefox 71 in mac os, i'd like to use ctrl+1 to switch to previous tab rather than command+shift+tab, how to achieve this?

i tried an add-on called custom key but not working,
i also tried to unpacking and modify omni.ja firefox binaryfile, but not working

is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

By unpacking binaryfile and modify,it is working, but modifiers="accel" refer to 'command' key in mac os not 'control'